# What columns are considered when JOIN is used without join criteria in Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

If you have two tables, `a` and `b` and you do following (that is, omit the join criteria a.k.a. `ON` clause), which column(s) is used for the join?

```
SELECT *
FROM a
JOIN b
```

I assume it looks for columns of the same name.

The [docs indicate](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-join.html) it will be an INNER JOIN but I don't see anywhere that it specifies which columns will be considered to join on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None. You get a cartesian product, based just on per partitions content.

Comment: Thanks. So in other words, it's a cross join?

Can you elaborate on the "per partitions content"? Does that mean that if both tables are partitioned on date, for example, only the rows with the same date will be cross joined?

Comment: See https://towardsdatascience.com/make-computations-on-large-cross-joined-spark-dataframes-faster-6cc36e61a222?gi=c0f281cee200. There is no where clause, so no mapping or column, hashing considerations.